# Making Abbreviation - selecting first character of non-stopwords

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, nltk

Given a list of stopwords and a dataframe with 1 column having full forms as shown -

```
stopwords = ['of', 'and', '&', 'com', 'org']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Full form': ['World health organization', 'Intellectual property', 'royal bank of canada']})
df

+---+---------------------------+
|   |         Full form         |
+---+---------------------------+
| 0 | World health organization |
| 1 | Intellectual property     |
| 2 | Royal bank of canada      |
+---+---------------------------+
```

I'm looking for a way to bring an adjacent column with their Abbreviation ignoring stopwords (if any).

Expected output:

```
+---+---------------------------+----------------+
|   |         Full form         |   Abbreviation |
+---+---------------------------+----------------+
| 0 | World health organization |   WHO          |
| 1 | Intellectual property     |   IP           |
| 2 | Royal bank of canada      |   RBC          |
+---+---------------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

stopwords = ['of', 'and', '&', 'com', 'org']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Full form': ['World health organization', 'Intellectual property', 'royal bank of canada']})


def abbrev(t, stopwords=stopwords):
    return ''.join(u[0] for u in t.split() if u not in stopwords).upper()


df['Abbreviation'] = df['Full form'].apply(abbrev)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                   Full form Abbreviation
0  World health organization          WHO
1      Intellectual property           IP
2       royal bank of canada          RBC
```

Comment: That's quick. Thanks @Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
df['Abbreviation'] = (df['Full form'].replace(stopwords, '', regex=True)
                      .str.split()
                      .apply(lambda word: [l[0].upper() for l in word])
                      .str.join(''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex solution:

```
stopwods = ['of', 'and', '&', 'com', 'org']
stopwords_re = r"(?!" + r"\b|".join(stopwords) + r"\b)"
abbv_re = r"\b{}\w".format(stopwords_re)

def abbrv(s):
    return "".join(re.findall(abbv_re, s)).upper()
```

[out]:

```
>>> abbrv('royal bank of scotland')
'RBS'
```

To use with pandas:

```
df['Abbreviation'] = df['Full form'].apply(abbrv)
```

---

For full explanation of the regex see: https://regex101.com/r/3Q0XXF/1

In brief,

- `\b{}\w`: Find all characters after the word boundary
- `(?!of\b|and\b|&\b)`: unless it's in a list of stopwords